# Router work as IPsec client to Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, mikrotik, vpn-client

Is it possible to configure mikrotik as IPsec vpn client to Cisco Asa? I have ASA connected with static IP to the internet and want to connect mikrotik router behind dynamic IP internet connection to the ASA and I think the most desired connection is router working as VPN client but can't find how to configure mikrotik as IPsec VPN client

Comment: Yes it's possible. Documentation: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/IPsec

Answer (score 0):

Here is your tutorial from gregsowell:
[gregsowell mikrotik](https://youtu.be/U-8RmkNpgWI)

Comment: you have idea at which minute he mention my scenario ? I mean IPsec VPN client to ASA with xauth

Comment: https://youtu.be/U-8RmkNpgWI?t=2404

Comment: This Mikrotik to ASA part ,I am not sure about xauth though.

Comment: Mikrotik supports PSK+XAuth and RSA+XAuth. Which one is in question?